# Good image manipulation utility for .Net based applications

Tags: .net, image-manipulation

I looking for a good image manipulation library/utility for using in .Net based application.

What I need it to do?

- Reduce the size of the image, by supplying a width value. but save the look of the image.
- Reduce the weight of the image, by optimizing it to web suffering.

The following thing are a good plus:

- Add a watermark to the image, both with (x,y) coordinates, or relative manner, like: center, bottom-left etc.
- Supporting  as many formats as possible, and converting the pictures from format to format.
- Detect if a .gif file is animated image or regular one. If it is, support resizing  animated pictures too is needed.

I know this is a lot of features, but in my opinion all of them are needed in today's websites, so I'm looking for a good one at least to be existed...

---

**Edit:** after that I experienced ImageMagick.Net wrapper, I can say that this is NOT ready library for production.

Do we have any more options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of them

1. [CoolWatermark](http://www.imagecomponent.net/)
2. [ImageDraw](http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/IDWebC/ImageDrawWebControl.aspx?tabid=24&prodid=4&gclid=CNPq6Lmj-58CFRKiagod71oylg)

Comment: +1, I have ImageDraw SDK, it's just an amazing lib to make effects on images and text without effort.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has been around for a while.  It has a .net wrapper called [MagickNet](http://midimick.com/magicknet/)

It's even got its own [Stack Overflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick)

I found a few links for it:

- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx)
- [Code Plex](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)

Code Plex seems to be the most active

Comment: +1 I know Imagemagick can do almost everything on that list. Not sure about resizing animated GIFs (I know it can create them)

Comment: Why MagickNet site is marked as fishing site according to ABP?

Comment: ImageMagick have a very poor .net wrapper :(

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/)

There is a Image processing namespace.

I only used the motion detction routines, but this was a good solid library.

Hope this helps

Comment: This library is for research and learning purpose more then for production sites. And it does not doing the things that I want it to to.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft

Our product, DotImage, can do this.  You'd need DotImage Photo to do it http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/photo

If you download and install an evaluation copy, we'll take you to a page where you can request a custom demo.  A link to this question would suffice for a spec.

Comment: I looking for an open source solution.